# Abantecart extension solution

Tags: php, open-source, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am developing git certificate extension for abantecart and encounter small issue.

I need to hook to the order and allow customer to provide details for gift certificate, such as name and email for recipient.

I found 2 solutions:

1. Use product (gift certificate in this case) options with name and email for recipient. This will be required before product is added to cart. 
   Advantage: Easy. 
   Disadvantage: No way to validate input
2. Hook into the checkout process (final step) and if product purchased is gift certificate, ask for details for it. 
   Advantage: More control
   Disadvantage: I do not know how to do this.

Any suggestions, what way should I go?
I need help on example how can I hook to checkout controller

Thanks you.

Comment: I taged by mistake. There is no tag for abantecart yet. sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

1. create file inside your extension directory, for ex. core/hooks.php and include this into main.php. ex: `include_once('core/hooks.php');`
2. write inside hooks.php something like this:

   ```
   class ExtensionYourExtensionTextId extends Extension {

     public function onControllerCheckoutConfirm_InitData() {

         $this->baseObject->view->addHookVar('payment_pre', 'your value'));
         //or change array data of base controller
        $this->baseObject->data['some_key'] = 'your value';

    return ;}
   }
   ```

You can find more info on http://www.abantecart.com/document_wiki/index.php/AbanteCart_Extension%E2%80%99s_Developer_Guide#Hooks